The "Review queues" dropdown erroneously indicates tasks in the queue
After taking care of the review queue, the dropdown still indicates outstanding tasks in the "Low Quality Posts" queue. The issue persists after refreshing the page. Can anyone confirm it or comment on this?


I can confirm this is rather usual issue. And it only happens when there is an increased number of items that require attention.

There's a fairly large amount of caching going on, as well as "notify you and then check if you can actually do anything" - for example: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389434/33051 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/302093/33051

I have not had this issue, but I have just dealt with the remaining 'Low quality post' in the queue so it should be cleared (at the time of posting).
If it has not cleared, it might be worth checking that you have no filters applied or perhaps waiting a few hours.


My filter settings look the same, but now after waiting a few hours the indicator is indeed gone.
